# How to load Image in ios UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, asynchronous, photo, uipageviewcontroller

```
func viewPhotoDetalController(index: Int) -> PhotoDetailViewController? {
    if let storyboard = storyboard,
        detailController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotoDetail")
            as? PhotoDetailViewController {
        //loadPhoto()
        return detailController
    }
    return nil
}
```

when swipe left or right in `UIPageViewController` the above code is called,
before return the detailController I want to load the photo and set the detailController's photo variable like this

```
func loadPhoto (index:Int) {
    let imgManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    imgManager.requestImageForAsset(self.devicePhotosAsset[self.index] as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
            // set the detailController's photo here

        })

}
```

but the problem is `requestImageForAsset` is a asynchronous api, by the time photo loaded the detailController is returned. also `requestImageForAsset` api's return type if void, so I can't do something like

```
imgManager.requestImageForAsset(self.devicePhotosAsset[self.index] as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
            detailController.photo = result
            return detailController

        })
```

so how can i set detailController's photo variable ?

here is full code of detailController, I follow the UIScrollView tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122139/uiscrollview-tutorial)

```
import UIKit
import Photos


class PhotoDetailViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var devicePhotosAsset : PHFetchResult!
var index = 0
var photo : UIImage!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView : UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.displayPhoto()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
}

func displayPhoto () {
    let imgManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    _ = imgManager.requestImageForAsset(self.devicePhotosAsset[self.index] as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
            self.imageView.image = result

        })

}

private func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(size: CGSize) {
    let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
    let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
    let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale

    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
}

private func updateConstraintsForSize(size: CGSize) {

    let yOffset = max(0, (size.height - imageView.frame.height) / 2)
    imageViewTopConstraint.constant = yOffset
    imageViewBottomConstraint.constant = yOffset

    let xOffset = max(0, (size.width - imageView.frame.width) / 2)
    imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xOffset
    imageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = xOffset

    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

extension PhotoDetailViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updateConstraintsForSize(view.bounds.size)
 }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you perform the image loading logic inside the DetailViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the PHAsset to PhotoDetailViewController and in its viewdidload make the call to download the image

```
 imgManager.requestImageForAsset(phasset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
                self.photo = result

            })
```

If their is any issue let me know

Comment: This won't work,photo has to be loaded in page controller

Comment: Why it can't be loaded in viewdidload??

Comment: It will work but in detailController I use scrollView to make the image zoomable, load image here will cause the initial photo scales very large

Comment: You have to solve than the initial photo scale otherwise you would have to download images synchronously which will work but it will halt the screen.Will that work for you??

Comment: BTW page controller is suppose to scroll smoothly with animation

Comment: please checkout the updated code, your answer is exactly what i did, but when the photo load it did not centered and only show a part of photo, but scroll and zoom works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112315/discussion-between-ahmad-ishfaq-and-paynestrike).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use closure as clouser captures the variables and constants of the context in which it is defined.So using closure you can solve your as

```
func viewPhotoDetalController(index: Int) -> PhotoDetailViewController? {
    if let storyboard = storyboard,
        detailController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotoDetail")
            as? PhotoDetailViewController {
        loadPhoto(2, completionHandler: {[weak self] (image) in
            detailController.imageView.image = image
        })
        return detailController
    }
    return nil
}
```

and loadPhoto method will look like this

```
func loadPhoto(index:Int,completionHandler:(image:UIImage?)->())  {
    let imgManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    imgManager.requestImageForAsset(self.devicePhotosAsset[self.index] as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
        completionHandler(image: result)
    })
}
```